# What are SQlite and WinRT default date format (Locale)

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

The Date format for USA is MM/DD/YYYY and British is DD/MM/YYYY.
The WinRT Tablet will set the Date Format base on the TimeZone when you First Turn on it for setting.

Let say I am setting my WinRT tablet to use British Date Format ( DD/MM/YYYY) and use this code to insert date into SQLite .

```
Class Order
      {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int SId { get; set; }
        public int CustId { get; set; }     
        public string No { get; set; }        
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }

      }



   using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
     {
        var newOrder = new Order()
        {
           CustId = g_intCustId,
           Customer = txtBlkCustomer.Text.Trim(),
           Order_Date = DateTime.Today   

        };

   db.Insert(newOrder);
```

1) What will be the Date format store by SQLite ? USA or British Date Format ?

2) How to set the date locale ( USA date or British date ) for SQLite database?

3) If above (2) is done, then the select statement (SQL-statement) base on date will base on the locale set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using [system.data.sqlite](/questions/tagged/system.data.sqlite).

According documentation, there is a `DateTimeFormat` parameter in `SQLiteConnection´` parameters which will specify how `DateTime` is handled in database:

> Ticks - Use the value of DateTime.Ticks.
>
> ISO8601 - Use the ISO-8601 format. Uses the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK" format for UTC
>   DateTime values and "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF" format for local
>   DateTime values).
>
> JulianDay - The interval of time in days and
>   fractions of a day since January 1, 4713 BC.
>
> UnixEpoch - The whole
>   number of seconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).
>
> InvariantCulture - Any culture-independent string value that the .NET
>   Framework can interpret as a valid DateTime.
>
> CurrentCulture - Any
>   string value that the .NET Framework can interpret as a valid DateTime
>   using the current culture.

Default is `ISO8601`. There is also a "custom" `DateTimeFormatString` and a `DateTimeKind` to specif UTF or local date times.

Comment: When I use DateTime.Today or DateTime.Now , are they Default ISO8601?

Comment: No. `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Now` are [tag:c#] `DateTime` data type. When you store `DateTime` data in [tag:SQLite] database, [tag:System.Data.SQLite] connector convert `DateTime` to an ISO8601 formatted SQLite `Text` type.

Comment: Is it OK to use Order_Date = DateTime.Today where Order_Date is DateTime DataType? Sqlite will handle DateTime.Today and put it in Order_Date as you say. To query the date in Sqlite, I must remember to use. example : "Select * from tblCustomer where Order_date ==" date('2013-10-12') base on yyyy-mm-dd format ?

Comment: You are diverging from first question. If dates are stored in database as ISO8601, you can just `SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE DATE(Order_date)='2013-10-12'`. Better would be to bind a parameter: [prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.createcommand.aspx) a `SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE DATE(Order_date)=DATE(?)`, then [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.parameters.aspx) any `DateTime`, and finally [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should never store localized dates in a database; this will break if the locale changes, and such strings do not sort correctly.

Either use the format `yyyy-mm-dd` (which is [the only one supported by the internal SQLite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), and the only one where comparisons work correctly), or store timestamps [as numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: Base on LS_dev above, my  Order_Date = DateTime.Today  is OK? Is DateTime,Today or DateTime.Now  mean UTC DateTime value ? SQLite will handle DateTime.Today as yyyy-mm-dd and insert it into Order_Date ?

Comment: Can u give me an example of Localized date?